# javascript logical operator doesn't return correct value

Tags: javascript

I have code like this.

```html
No1 : <input type="text" name="no1">  value = 45
No2 : <input type="text" name="no2">  value = 55

<script>
      var no1 = $('input[name=no1]').val();
      var no2 = $('input[name=no2]').val();
</script>
```

But I check like this, it always returns `false`.

```
parseFloat(no1) < parseFloat(no2);
//false
```

Please explain theory behind this. I am new to javascript. I couldn't find it google either.

Comment: What's the value in each?

Comment: I assume you are using jquery selector. Are you sure have supply reference to jquery.js inside the page? What is the value of no1 and no2?

Comment: use your browser's console to check what your numbers are: insert `console.log(no1, no2)` in the script.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as it stands right now, both inputs have an empty value, so `parseFloat` gives `NaN`, which is not comparable therefore any comparison involving it will be false.

Comment: I have entered value (45 & 55 etc) to the text fields.

Comment: I know that. 55 > 45 also false.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Kolink Try this.

```html
No1 : <input type="text" name="no1">
No2 : <input type="text" name="no2">

<script>
      var no1 = document.getElementsByName('no1')[0].value;
      var no2 = document.getElementsByName('no2')[0].value;
      // will evaluate properly as long as you supply number inside input text
      parseFloat(no1) > parseFloat(no2);
</script>
```

Comment: And note that *both* input texts need numbers inside them, otherwise the comparison always returns false. If you want it to treat an empty field as a 0 you could evaluate something like `parseFloat(no1 || 0) > parseFloat(no2 || 0)`

Comment: Hi Derek, I assume in Priyanga case the value of no1 and no2 will never initiated properly because he try to use jQuery selector which is perhaps never referenced anywhere inside of his page that make no1 and no2 value to be 'undefined' and parseFlot will return NaN. I just offer simpler document.getElementsByName solution which as long     we supply number to input text it will return correct value. In the case of he supply invalid value, I think everyone has to provide proper validation inside their code. Thank you very much for Stuart for correcting some of my mistake.

Comment: @JonKartagoLamida - `never referenced anywhere inside of his page that make no1 and no2 value to be 'undefined'` Wait what?

Comment: Hey all, I entered values in textfields 45 & 55. when I log it console it prints nicely.